# HTML <thead> with background image rendering difference between IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a table coded in HTML as follows;

```
<table border="1" class="tableBasic">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Head Row 1</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Head Row 1</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Head Row 1</th>
        <th colspan="4">Head Row 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Head Row 2</th>
        <th>Head Row 2</th>
        <th>Head Row 2</th>
        <th>Head Row 2</th>
    </tr>

</thead>
</table>
```

So this is a table header spanning 2 rows.

```
.tableBasic thead{
    background: url("/images/tbl_header.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Is there a rendering difference for the background image between IE and Firefox?

While IE shows the background image as spanning 2 rows (i.e. equals 2 row height), Firefox just shows it for the first row (and does not show any background for the 2nd row)

The background image is tall enough to span 2 rows height.
Unfortunately I won't be able to modify the HTML code and only can control this from the CSS.

How do I fix this issue in CSS?

**IE**
[image]

**Firefox**
[image]

Comment: A picture showing the difference would be nice.

Comment: Added the picture now...Just see how the Head Row 2 also has the background in IE....I want it similarly in Firefox as well..

Comment: My suspicion is that the firefox is the correct rendering. You can see in the first 3 columns, that it's going more than 1 row (not quite 2) in both FF & IE

Comment: @Alastair Pitts, I do agree with you and also think FF is doing the correct rendering. I do like IE's rendering better though (rare occasion!) :)

Comment: Yes, Bcoz IE's rendering looks much better in this case, I want it to look similar in Firefox...

Comment: But IE's rendering is incorrect, besides it doesn't cope well with the taller cells on the left. So you DEFINITELY need another approach to cater for all cases. :)

Comment: Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. What doctype are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Firefox is doing what you said, you declared the background on thead and repeat only X, so that's what Firefox is doing. IE is cheating a little which makes it look better, but it's not following your css declaration. Since you have another little issue to solve, namely the fact that some cells are taller than others and one image won't do it, I think you should consider aiming your css at the `th` elements instead.

Perhaps something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JQK2A/1/

You can define the appropriate background image according to the colspan or rowspan attribute.

CSS

```
.tableBasic thead th {
    background: green url(background.jpg);
}

.tableBasic thead th[rowspan] {
    background: red url(background2.jpg); 
}

.tableBasic thead th[colspan] {
    background: blue url(background3.jpg); 
}
```

UPDATE after comment:

If you are OK with using CSS 3, you could try this (using just 1 background image):

```
.tableBasic thead th {
    background: url(background.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%; /* CSS 3 */
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot...I just tried this out...But does not seem to be working the way I want....I just want to have 1 background image and it should span the entire height in both IE and Firefox...

Comment: neither your IE nor your FF screenshot shows this behaviour. Can you elaborate? How does your background image cope with taller and less tall cells? You should either let it repeat Y or have a VERY tall background image.

Comment: Please see also my CSS 3 example.